# jQuery $.getJSON sending string

Tags: jquery

I am trying to sending a string "idToken" with $.getJSON command

```
  $.getJSON('/firebase_token', idToken, function(uid) {
    console.log(uid);
  })
```

The backend receives the idToken sent, but it is displayed as "undefined" from req.body

```
router.get("/firebase_token", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
})
```

I would like to do send the string, and the backend receives it as a string, does some manipulation and send it back as a string to the front-end.
I am using

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you inspect the network request in your browser's developer tools? Which data is sent?

Comment: The data is sent as a URL parameter, not as the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.getJSON` sends a `GET` request. There's no request body, the parameter is sent as the URL query string.

Do it like this:

```
$.getJSON('/firebase_token', {token: idToken}, function(uid) {
    console.log(uid);
})
```

and then you can access it with:

```
router.get("/firebase_token", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.token);
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, but why I cannot send a string to the backend using $.getJSON? I read on the jQuery documentation that the second parameter can be whether an object or a string.  Also, why there is not req.body with jquery?

Comment: This is the same as sending the string `'token=' + encodeURIComponent(idToken)`. You can also send just `idToken`, but I don't know how to read it in Express if there's no parameter name. I could only find `req.query.XXX` where `XXX` is the name.

Comment: There's no `req.body` with `$.getJSON()` because it sends `GET` rather than `POST`. Use `$.post()` or `$.ajax()` if you want to send a body.